# vb.net geckowebbrowser getelementbyid

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the Geckowebbrowser from geckofx45
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geckofx45/45.0.34

Let's say I have this HTML code :  `<div id="N01">Hello World !</div>`
I would like to get "Hello World !" into a textbox when  press a button

I know how to do it with the common webbrowser but not with the geckowebbrowser

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
         textbox1.text = geckowebbrowser1.    ?????????????????
    End Sub
```

Do someone have an idea please ?

Comment: You couldn't have done much research or testing at all... It's literally the exact same syntax as with the regular WebBrowser.

Comment: @Visual Vincent I would say TextBox1.Text = GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("....").innerhtml     but it tells me innerhtml in not a part of Geckoelement... And if i remember good ( i m noob) i used innertext and not innerhtml...

Comment: Well at least you got the `GetElementById()` part. It's important to share your attempts in the question ;). See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Gecko you must first cast/convert to a `GeckoHtmlElement` before you can access properties such as `InnerHtml`:

```
TextBox1.Text = CType(GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("N01"), GeckoHtmlElement).InnerHtml
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and your help. Best regards